# The series converging to a point

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can someone please tell how to solve.
The series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n^2 +3n +1)}{ ( n+2)!}$$ converges to?

Comment: Please type your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Moreover, please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: So, what method have you tried here?

Comment: @Mark Viola: You mean $n^2+3n+2 =\ ...$

Comment: 8-) $\quad$ Mark ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $ n^2+3n+2 = (n+1)(n+2)$, so we can split the series' general term in two parts: $\frac{n^2+3n+1}{(n+2)!} = \frac{n^2+3n+2}{(n+2)!} - \frac{1}{(n+2)!} = \frac{1}{n!} - \frac{1}{(n+2)!}$. Now, looking at the partial sums, the sum of the first $p$ terms is a telescopic sum, which evaluates to: $\frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!}  - \frac{1}{(p+1)!} - \frac{1}{(p+2)!}$, so the answer is $2$ :). Hopefully, I haven't messed up the computations.

Comment: You're very welcome :)